# How a can make foreach with GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an GridView with DB informations.
In my aspx, I have 2 checkbox.
I need make check in one checkbox for each row according to AccessType value.
How I can capture AccessType value in foreach?

My aspx (GridView)

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="AccessGroup" HeaderText="Access Group" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FolderAccess" HeaderText="Folder Access" />
                    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="group_manager" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="groupinfo.aspx?group={0}"
                        DataTextField="group_manager" HeaderText="Group Manager" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="AccessType" Visible="false" />
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Access to Read" />
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Text="Access to Modify" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

My .cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        var listaProdutos = new RequestAccess().ConsultarProdutos();
        if (listaProdutos != null)
        {
            this.GridView.DataSource = listaProdutos;
            this.GridView.DataBind();

            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox check = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
                CheckBox check2 = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox2");


                //EX!!!
                //IF AccessType = 1
                //{
                //    check.Checked = true;
                //}

                //IF AccessType = 2
                //{
                //    check2.Checked = true;
                //}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use `RowDataBound` instead of an additional `foreach`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can access `BoundFields` via `e.Row.Cells[index].Text`:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView.Rows)
{
    string accessType = row.Cells[3].Text;
}
```

However, I would use `RowDataBound` instead of an additional `foreach`.

Here is the `RowDataBound` event which is raised for every row in the `GridView` when it was databound. Assuming the `DataSource` is something like a `DataTable`:

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox check = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
        CheckBox check2 = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("CheckBox2");
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        int accesType = row.Field<int>("AccessType");
        check.Checked = accesType == 1;
        check2.Checked = accesType == 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tks, Tim! But, one more question. How I can set this value (AccessType) without get it in ASPX? How I can get this value (AccessType) directly in CS? Can help me? I see no need to pass this value to my aspx.

Comment: @CaioVJesus89: Sorry, i must admit that i have not understood that comment. Do you mean pass "to the client"? Then, no, you are not sending it to the client if the `BoundField` is invisible.

Comment: Apology my english! I'm passing AccessType value for aspx. I don't see necessary. I believe that have some way to get this value and pass it inside my FOREACH straight through. CS

Comment: @CaioVJesus89: So you don't want to use a `BoundField` at all but instead you want to use the datasource? Btw, what does `ConsultarProdutos` return, a `DataTable`?

Comment: @CaioVJesus89: Edited my answer to incluse the `RowDataBound` approach  to show you how you can access the datasource directly. If the cast to `DataRowView` fails you have to use the debugger to inspect the actual type of `e.Row.DataItem`.

Comment: Tim, ConsultaProdutos return a List, an List of ModeloProdutos (List<ModeloProdutos> PreencheValores(SqlDataReader reader)). And in List<ModeloProdutos> I have AccessType (modeloProdutos.AccessType = Convert.ToInt32(reader["AccessType"].ToString());)

Answer (score 1):

You could add the AccessType value to a HiddenField within the grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        onrowdatabound="GridView_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AccessGroup" HeaderText="Access Group" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FolderAccess" HeaderText="Folder Access" />
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="group_manager" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="groupinfo.aspx?group={0}"
                    DataTextField="group_manager" HeaderText="Group Manager" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AccessType" Visible="false" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnAccessType" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("AccessType") %>' />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkReadOnly" runat="server" Enabled="false" />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkModify" runat="server" Enabled="false" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

and then use the RowDataBound event handler to get the AccessType value from the HiddenField control and set the checkbox accordingly:

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HiddenField hdnAccessType = (HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("hdnAccessType");
            int accessType = int.Parse(hdnAccessType.Value.ToString());
            CheckBox chkReadOnly = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkReadOnly");
            CheckBox chkModify = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkModify");

            switch (accessType)
            {
                case 1:
                    chkReadOnly.Checked = true;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    chkModify.Checked = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.